# @GeneratorValue выдаёт уже занятые id

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Таблица: `"ID" INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('zakazchik_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,`
Сущность:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "\"ID\"", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "\"zakazchik_seq_gen\"")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "\"zakazchik_seq_gen\"", sequenceName = "\"zakazchik_id_seq\"")
private Integer id;
```

При вставке новой строки пишет:

```
    ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique  
 constraint "zakazchik_new_new1_new_pk_zakaz"  
      Подробности: Key ("ID")=(730) already exists.
```

Всё правильно, 730 id уже занят... и так до 743.
Через hibernate только сейчас начал работать, до этого всё было через jdbc с жутким собиратором sql-запросов.
Почему он начал назначать старые id начиная с 700-го, я же ему указал `zakazchik_id_seq`?

Comment: какое значение выдает на БД `select last_value from zakazchik_id_seq`? Также попробуйте добавить в аннотацию `@Column` -  `updatable = false, nullable = false`  и в аннотацию `SequenceGenerator` - `allocationSize=1`

Comment: @Chubatiy 759. Ничего не понимаю. Всего 743 записи.

Comment: @Chubatiy да, помогло. А вы можете объяснить почему помогло? Почему так странно брало id из последовательности?

Comment: Алгоритм получения значений. По-умолчанию 50. Если надо щёлкать каждый раз - надо установить `allocationSize=1`

Comment: добавил в ответ и ссылку на источник

Answer (score 2, accepted):

необходимо установить

```
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "zakazchik_seq_gen", sequenceName = "zakazchik_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

По-умолчанию Hibernate использует алгоритм HiLo и резервирует 50 значений.

[Вот описание на хабре](https://habr.com/post/349250/)